# Script prints undefined when I just want to show the time

Tags: javascript, html

So here's my script

```js
function updateClock() {
  var now = new Date(); // current date
  var time = now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes(); // again, you get the idea
  // a cleaner way than string concatenation
  // set the content of the element with the ID time to the formatted string
  document.getElementById('nav-time').innerHTML = time;
  // call this function again in 1000ms
  setTimeout(updateClock, 1000);
}
```

```html
<li><span id="nav-time">Time
<script>document.write(updateClock());</script></span></li>
<span class="divider"> | </span>
```

But when the webpage loads, for the first second it is displayed it always has `undefined` at the end of the time string like `12:12undefined`.

Comment: If you only want minutes you can use a much longer interval here than 1 second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call your function in the `document.write`. You can just add the script into your page. Call the `setInterval` (I want to show time every second, not `setTimeout`) outside of the function itself. Also access the element via `document.getElementById` and store in a variable to add more performance.

```js
const el = document.getElementById('nav-time');

function updateClock() {
   var now = new Date();
   var time = now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds(); 
        
   el.innerHTML = time;    
}

setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
```

```html
<li><span id="nav-time">Time
<span class="divider"> | </span>
```

Comment: Perhaps use a longer interval than 1?

Comment: Sorry. Forgot `000` part